# How to add custom footer (with gradient) in ios 8 to UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm able to add a custom status bar (with gradient) to the UIView like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var statusBar : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 375, height: 20))
    let statusBarGradient : CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    statusBarGradient.frame = statusBar.bounds
    let cor1 = UIColor(red: 0.416, green: 0.604, blue: 0.796, alpha: 1.0)
    let cor2 = UIColor.whiteColor()
    let arrayColors = [cor1.CGColor, cor2.CGColor]
    statusBarGradient.colors = arrayColors
    view.layer.insertSublayer(statusBarGradient, atIndex:0)
}
```

I would also like to add the same gradient to the footer but I'm not having much luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works if you add the statusBar as a subview of the view, but I would make it dynamically size the width to fit the width of the superview, so just do the same thing for the footer, but dynamically set the height to be whatever the height of your view is minus the desired height of your footer bar.

```
let statusBar = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 20))
let footer = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.height - 20.0, width: view.frame.width, height: 20))
let statusBarGradient = CAGradientLayer()
let footerGradient = CAGradientLayer()

statusBarGradient.frame = statusBar.bounds
let cor1 = UIColor(red: 0.416, green: 0.604, blue: 0.796, alpha: 1.0)
let cor2 = UIColor.blackColor()
let arrayColors = [cor1.CGColor, cor2.CGColor]

footerGradient.frame = footer.bounds

let arrayColorsFooter = [cor2.CGColor, cor1.CGColor]
statusBarGradient.colors = arrayColors
footerGradient.colors = arrayColorsFooter

statusBar.layer.insertSublayer(statusBarGradient, atIndex:0)
footer.layer.insertSublayer(footerGradient, atIndex:0)
view.addSubview(statusBar)
view.addSubview(footer)
```